# Nested resource with a singular parent that has... a plural name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, form-for

A user has a singular set of their 'preferences'. The resource aught to be singular because a user has just one set of preferences that they should be aware of. The name should be plural, because that resource represents a plethora of settings. I'm having a problem now with routing, and I believe it stems from this.

I have declared the route,

```
  resource 'preferences', only: [:show, :edit, :update] do
    resources :weight_based_rates
  end
```

The output from running `rake routes` contains the following entries,

```
    preferences_weight_based_rates GET      /preferences/weight_based_rates(.:format)          weight_based_rates#index
                                   POST     /preferences/weight_based_rates(.:format)          weight_based_rates#create
 new_preferences_weight_based_rate GET      /preferences/weight_based_rates/new(.:format)      weight_based_rates#new
edit_preferences_weight_based_rate GET      /preferences/weight_based_rates/:id/edit(.:format) weight_based_rates#edit
     preferences_weight_based_rate GET      /preferences/weight_based_rates/:id(.:format)      weight_based_rates#show
```

Then, in a relevant partial I declare a form like so,

```
= form_for [@preference, WeightBasedRate.new], :remote => true do |f|
```

And, finally, I get a `NoMethodError in Preferences#show

```
undefined method `preference_weight_based_rates_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000572d2b0>:0x000000057b4800>
```

Note that the method so undefined involves 'preference' in the singular.

Perhaps I am betraying a degree of naivety, but it wouldn't be the first time the magic of Rails has undone me: is rails constructing a singular name based on some assumption about the singularity of my model? Or maybe based on the fact that I am passing an instance? Is rails then unable to put the pieces together? Have I just arranged poorly the arguments to form_for?

Is rails confused, or am I?

Comment: That seems strange, I would expect your show route to be `preference_weight_based_rate` (not pluralized preferences). I'm looking through some of my routes and it seems to be consistently singular in edit and show routes.

Comment: Yeah, the convention is to name a singular resource with a singular name, like 'preference'. I'm wondering if my choice to name it a name that has an 's' on the end has confused things. Like, maybe rails is saying "hey this is a singular resource, so the word 'preferences' must be the singular noun that denotes it."